# Could not deduce template argument for 'const' ... from int

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-c++

I have a templated function

```
template<typename It>
void Foo(It first, It second)
{
    It third = first;
    Bar(first, second, third);
}
```

which calls another templated function

```
template<typename It>
void Bar(It first,It second,It third)
{
    for(It j= first + 2; j < second; j++)
    {
        third++;
    }
}
```

When I call `Foo`with the code

```
std::list<int> l{ 3, 8, 2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 6 };
Foo(l.begin(), l.end());
```

I get several errors referring to the line

```
for(It j= first + 2; j < second; j++)
```

in Foo. The first error message is

> Error C2784   'std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> std::operator
>   +(reverse_iterator<_RanIt>::difference_type,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &)': could not deduce template argument
>   for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from
>   'int' AlgorithmsTests

What do I have to change to make the code snippet work?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70de46a3e4c8353f)

Comment: You are making something up. Nothing you posted so far would bring into the picture reverse iterators. In reality you are doing something else. What is it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @AnT Faced with an overload set with no viable candidate, some compiler prints out every possible overload found by name lookup and why they don't match, including completely irrelevant ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
for(It j= first + 2; j < second; j++)
```

should not be a problem when `It` is `std::vector<int>::iterator`. However, that won't necessarily work for all types iterators. Use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) instead.

Also, `j < second` would not work for non-random-access iterators either. Thanks, @T.C.

Use:

```
It j = first;
std::advance(j,2);
for( ; j != second; j++)
```

Another, a more elegant, option (Thanks, @AnT):

```
for( It j = std::next(first, 2) ; j != second; j++)
```

Comment: Nor would `<` work for non-random-access iterators. And there's `std::next`.